# ASP.NET MVC Controller Result return to view

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I'm working in ASP MVC & C#, and what i'm trying to do is something similar to the following.

```
public JsonResult SendMessage(SMSTestViewModel model)
{
    if (//logic here)
    {
        string phonenumber = model.phone.ToString();
        string derp = string.Empty;
        //SMS.SendSMS(phonenumber, "testing heheheheh", derp);
        var result = new { Success = "True", Message = "Good Job" };
        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    var result = new { Success = "False", Message = "Didn't work" };
    return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

That's the code block in my controller, and now I'm trying to reference this in my View with the following

```
<p>Please enter your phone number</p>
 <table>
  <tr>
    <td>Phone Number</td>
    <td> <input id = "phone" type ="text" name= "phone" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sendMSG">

<script>
 $('sendMSG').click(function(){
$.getJSON('SMSTestController/SendMessage', function (data) {
    alert(data.Success);
    alert(data.Message);
}); 
});
</script>
```

For some reason the alerts wont show up. And It's quite confusing to me.
I'm really new to JSON, JQuery and Javascript so any help or recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:

Changed the html code block to the following:

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" id="sendMSG">

 <script>
$('#sendMSG').click(function () {
    $.getJSON('@Url.Action("SendMessage","SMSTestController")', function (data) {
        alert(data.Success);
        alert("test");
        alert(data.Message);
    }); 
});
 </script>
```

Comment: What problem are you facing?

Comment: @Matt Houser the alert doesnt show up :( Sorry I dont even know why I didnt write that.

Comment: Does your click event trigger?  Does you action get called?  There are many points of failure here.  At what point in the pipeline do things break?

Comment: @user2094139: Is there an error in the JavaScript console?  Does the JavaScript code get executed at all?  If it does, does it successfully reach the controller action?

Comment: So I believe what I'm having an issue with is it reaching the controller action, as I have put several breakpoints within the JSonResult SendMessage, which I never end up hitting after clicking the submit button. –

Comment: Press F12 and see if there are any script errors, we can take it from there.

Comment: @Johan Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. ping:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined SMSTest:36 –

Comment: @user2094139 add an alert('test') within the click event, and see if it fires that

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't throw the alert either..

Comment: I've done this before using js by making a function and using the onclick in the button, but I wanted to figure out how to do it this wa

Comment: @user2094139 have you changed $('sendMSG') to $('#sendMSG')?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely, the URL in your `$.getJSON` call is incorrect. You have it relative to whatever URL you're currently looking at.

Try changing that line to be:

```
$.getJSON('@Url.Action("SendMessage", "SMSTestController")', function (data) {
```

This way, MVC generates an absolute URL to your action.

**Edit:**

Your jQuery selector of your button is wrong.

```
$('sendMSG')
```

Since you're searching for it by id, use:

```
$('#sendMSG')
```

Comment: So I believe what I'm having an issue with is it reaching the controller action, as I have put several breakpoints within the JSonResult SendMessage, which I never end up hitting after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Many browsers have built-in debugging tools.  Google Chrome and IE are F12 to show them.  Use the network tracker to see where your JSON call is attempting to go to.  Once you see that, that should give you an idea what is wrong.

Comment: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings.  It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains. ping:1
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined SMSTest:36

Comment: Did you include a link to include jQuery in your HTML?

Comment: honestly i dont understand what you mean.. is there a certain tag I have to add or something?

Comment: I've changed this, and I still find the same error. Thanks for catching that though.

Comment: Do you have something like `<script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js")"></script>` in the header of your HTML?

Comment: Thanks guys, I fiugured out I didnt need to have the word 'Controller' in the "SMSTestController" part of my code :D works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

Changing the url to the following should make it work

```
'/SMSTestController/SendMessage'
```

However, the better solution is as Matt had mentioned

```
'@Url.Action("SendMessage", "SMSTestController")'
```

Also, Have a look at this Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Ukuyc/